# Attempting find an embedded string in database with mysql

Tags: mysql, string, special-characters

I'm attempting to query our database to find specific types of transactions with unique parameters.

There are multiple formats and I'm looking to get the transactions with the -Q/ parameter.

```
BCR*DEVSTS  
BCR*1150  
BCR*1150/28AUG  
BCR*DEVSTS-Q/28AUG  
BCR*DEV-Q/28AUG
```

I'm able to find the `BCR` transactions but due to memory constraints I can only get the first 10k rows and they don't have the `-Q/` parameter.  I'm trying to create a query that will only select the required transactions.

I used the following to query for the basis transaction:

```
select * 
from transaction_200827 
where reqresponse= 'Q' and message rlike '^BCR.*'
```

I've reviewed multiple websites but haven't been able to find an example of this scenario.  I've tried variations on the examples provided and haven't been successful:

```
select * from transaction_200827 where reqresponse= 'Q' and message rlike '^BCR(Q/).*' 
select * from transaction_200827 where reqresponse= 'Q' and message rlike '^BCR%Q/%.*'
```

I'm fairly new to building queries and would appreciate any guidance or direction for generating this type of query.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing regexp and LIKE patterns. Use either

```
message LIKE 'BCR%-Q/%'
```

or

```
message RLIKE '^BCR.*-Q/'
```

You're also missing the `-` before `Q` in your patterns.

There's no need to add `.*` to the end of the regexp -- `RLIKE` succeeds when the regexp matches anywhere in the string, it doesn't have to match the entire string (the `^` anchor forces it to match starting from the beginning, but there's no `$` anchor extending it to the end).

If the column has an index, I recommend using `LIKE` -- in my experience, `RLIKE` doesn't take advantage of indexes. Either way, the index will only be used for matching the `BCR` at the beginning, the rest requires scanning all the values with that prefix.

Comment: Thank you Barmar.  I appreciate your help with this.